# Create a class in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to ASP.NET, and I'm trying to create a class that will call in aspx called **AddNode.aspx**, I have a few questions

1. How do I simply print a text in constructor/method, similar to *php* **echo** / *java* **system.out.print()**
2. How do I call the class in **AddNode.aspx**
3. How do I define a function (GetNode()) to return database result?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


public class category
{
    public category()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
        Response.Write("abc");
    }

    public static Array[] GetNode() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are indeed great differences between PHP and ASP .NET Web Forms (the differences are less in the case of ASP .NET MVC but they are still much) so I understand the source of confusion.

1-Are you using Web Forms? If so, you can add a Label control to the Form and then set it's Text property to some value you like. label1.Text = "Hello ASP .NET";

In the ASPX markup:
`<asp:label ID="label1" runat="server" text="Label">`

In the code behind file (associated with ASPX, right click on the designer and then choose View Code):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Hello ASP .NET";
    }
```

You can also use Response.Write("**Hello ASP .NET**"); But with this you have less control on where this text appears. Notice you can write HTML tags.

2-You have to distinguish between the class that represents the Web Form (exists in the code-behind file, note the ASP .NET term "code-behind") and other classes such as the one you made: "category" (in .NET it's a matter of convention that class names are capitalized: Category).

Call a class? If you mean create an instance of a class for some purpose, just write `category
 instance = new category();`. You can refer to static functionality in the class by writing category.StaticMemberName(); if it's a method.

3-That's a multifaceted question. Read about Data access in .NET...

You need to do lots of reading before asking questions like these! Good luck.

Comment: i have add
 public category()
 {
            Console.WriteLine("abc");

 }

at code behind of node.aspx.cs

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var category = new category();
        
       
    }

how can i print the string?

Comment: Do NOT use Console.WriteLine, it has nothing to do with the Web Server technology called ASP .NET. In my answer I mention two ways to print a string. 1-Response.Write("abc"); which is similar to PHP's echo or 2-Use a Web Forms "Label" control which you can add to your form manually by typing the markup (see my answer) or by dragging the Label from a Toolbox into the Form's design surface.

Answer (score 1):

asp.net webForm has different paradigm than PHP. try [Getting Started with ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/introduction-and-overview) or you can try to asp.net MVC ([Intro to ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3)) that more similar to PHP MVC framwork.